# I cannot correctly configure an Angular service test using a BehaviorSubject to emit a state object

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, behaviorsubject, angular-test

I have a service that makes an api call and then sets the values on a private state object and then emits an update to a behavior subject.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExeService {
  private state: IState = {
    things: {}  
  };

  public things$: BehaviorSubject<{ [key: string]: IThing }> = new BehaviorSubject<{ [key: string]: IThing }>(this.state.things);

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  public getThings() {
    this.http.get('/api/things').subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        this.state.things = res;
        this.things$.next(this.state.things)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I want to test these api calls and make sure they are setting the values correctly in the state and updating the behavior subject.

```
describe('ExeService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: ExeService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ExeService
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ]
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(ExeService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('Should get things', (done) => {

    service.getThings();
    service.things$.subscribe(things => {

      if (Object.keys(things).length) {
        expect(things).toEqual(MockedThings_ApiResponse);
        done();
      }

    });

    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`/api/things`);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush(MockedThings_ApiResponse);

  });
});
```

When the test executes it actually executes `getThings()` and evaluates the subscription to the behavior subject before the `req.flush`. As I conceptually understand it, the whole thing shouldnt evaulate until all the test parameters are provided. I end up with a 404 request to `http://localhost:9876/api/things` (the karma test port) and *then* it makes the test request. (I also get a ton of 404 warnings from SASS files trying to get font files not inside my app's directory, but thats another story).

In order to evaluate that I have the expected values I first have to check if the behavior subject has any values, hence the `Object.keys(things).length`. I think this essentially invalidates the test because if the service failed to set it then the `expect()` would never happen and thus have a false positive. However if I remove that then the test fails because of the initial subscription result returning `{}`.

**Question:** Do I not understand how this is supposed to work, or am I configuring my tests completely incorrectly?

Comment: I think it evaluates the subscription first because you're using a `BehaviorSubject`. If your intention is to verify whether the BehaviorSubject emitted the proper data or not, you could create a mock of `things$` and assert, for instance, of `things$.next` was called with the right arguments. Now I'm also wondering `HttpClientTestingModule` is needed here.